# Amateur licenced operation and wifi

Tags: wifi

Is it wise to use my call sign as SSID on 802.11x spectrum. I wish to be known.
My question more pointently is, is it common for amateurs to ID on shared common wifi frequencies.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use anything at all as the SSID for a wifi network. Absolutely anything.

Is it wise? I don't think it is unwise - in theory you and only a handful of other people will ever see your SSID, and most of them won't know what a KB1DMR is.